# I got 'fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory' but there is it

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use opencv 4.x library on C++.

When I run a test code on vscode, the error occured 'fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory'

But there is the file in the directory.

I checked vscode's json file and I set the include path correctly. I don't know why.

Can you tell me anything i missed?

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "C:\\minGW+opencv\\opencv\\build\\include"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.18362.0",
        "compilerPath": "C:/minGW+opencv/minGW/bin/g++.exe",
        "cStandard": "c17",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
```

}

I have that header file in the right path.
[image]

Comment: Where do you put the header files? Are you sure the header file path is `C:\\minGW+opencv\\opencv\\build\\include\\opencv2\\core.hpp`?

Comment: The error info `fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory` is a vscoce-cpp extension prompt or an error reported by compiler when you build the test code?

Comment: Did you also apply this path to `tasks.json` ?

Comment: @rustyhu Header files are in "C:\minGW+opencv\opencv\include\opencv2\core.hpp" And I set Includepath like that.

Comment: @drescherjm Already applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C:\\minGW+opencv\\opencv\\build\\include` is the wrong include path for your project. (it only contains cmake scripts, no actual headers)

assuming you did a proper `mingw32-make install` before (well, *did* you ??), it should be:

`C:\\minGW+opencv\\opencv\\build\\install\\include`

Comment: Oh I didn't. There's no 'install' folder in 'C:\\minGW+opencv\\opencv\\build'. Then, should I have opencv installed in mingw version?

Comment: yes, you have to build the libraries first (starting with cmake)

Comment: in the meantime, look up how to link libraries to your project (that will be the next problem ...)

Comment: we all start small, you know ...